# How to retrive value of listbox.valuemember property

Tags: c#, listbox

I beginner in c# programming.
I have filter the result in this mode:

```
listamicizie1.DisplayMember = "viewname"; // it's a alias
listamicizie1.ValueMember = "IdUtente"; //it's a primary key in my db table
listamicizie1.DataSource = ds.Tables["UTENTI"]; //db table
```

now I must register in another db table the value of the result of listbox and I use that code

```
    string idu = string.Empty;
    string value = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in listamicizie1.ValueMember)
    {        
       for (int j = 0; j < listamicizie1.Items.Count; j++)
       {
           idu = listamicizie1.SelectedValue;
           value += idu + ",";
       }
    }
    value = value.TrimEnd(',');
    value = value.TrimEnd(',');
    idutente = user.Text;
    string CnnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CnnStr"].ToString();
    string querysql2 = " INSERT INTO AMICIZIA (IdUtente1, [idamici]) VALUES ('" + idutente + "', '" + value + "')";
    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(querysql2, myconn);
    try
    {
       myconn.Open();
       mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
       myconn.Close();
    }    

  }
  this.Close();

}
```

The program running, but when I open my second db table (AMICIZIA), the value in idamici isn't the primary key ( idutente in the first table),but is i,d,u,t,e,n,t,e,.

How to retrive the original value of idutente?
Thanks

(sorry if I write whit some errors, but I'm not english :) )

Comment: First thing to fix: stop creating your SQL dynamically like that. Use parameterized SQL. That will stop SQL injection attacks, avoid conversion errors, and improve your code readability. Next, apply some diagnostics - log the value you're retrieving from the listbox. (It's not clear why you're looping through *every* item - the fact that you're not using `j` or `item` in your loop body is distinctly worrying...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `value.TrimEnd(',');` use `value.Replace(',', '');`

Also it is good practice to use `Parameters` instead of concatenated string.

```
        string idu = string.Empty;
        string value = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in listamicizie1.ValueMember)
        {


            for (int j = 0; j < listamicizie1.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                idu = listamicizie1.SelectedValue;
                value += idu + ",";
            }
        }
        //value = value.TrimEnd(',');
        //value = value.TrimEnd(',');
        value = value.Replace(',', '');
        value = value.Replace(' ', ''); //Add this line if you do not want space. 
        idutente = user.Text;
        string CnnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CnnStr"].ToString();
        string querysql2 = " INSERT INTO AMICIZIA (IdUtente1, idamici) VALUES ('" + @idutente,  @value)";
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
        SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(querysql2, myconn);
        try
        {
            myconn.Open();
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idutente", idutente);
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            myconn.Close();
        }


    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Added:

You can also change the code `value += idu + ",";` when you are generating the `value`, see the code

```
foreach (var item in listamicizie1.ValueMember)
{        
   for (int j = 0; j < listamicizie1.Items.Count; j++)
   {
       idu = listamicizie1.SelectedValue;
       value += idu.Trim(idu);
   }
}
//value = value.TrimEnd(',');
//value = value.TrimEnd(',');
```

Now no need to call `Replace`

Adding All items from list box **

Try this code.

```
        string CnnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CnnStr"].ToString();
        string querysql2 = " INSERT INTO AMICIZIA (IdUtente1, idamici) VALUES ('" + @idutente,  @value)";
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
        SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(querysql2, myconn);
        myconn.Open();

        for (int i=0; i < listamicizie1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var myitem = listamicizie1.Items[i];
            var dataArray = ( myitem as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray;
            //MessageBox.Show(dataArray[0].ToString());
            idutente = user.Text; //I don't know what are you storing here.
            value = dataArray[0].ToString(); //dataArray[0] should have key

            try
            {
              mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idutente", idutente);
              mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
              mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              mycmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
               return;
            }
            finally
            {
              myconn.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: In the db table the result is similar... from i,d,u,t,e,n,t,e to i d u t e n t e

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you don't was space as well, then add this `value = value.Replace(' ', '');`

Comment: thanks, but isn't that the problem, in the second dbtable i need the original value  the primary key from the first table. I have some users, and when I transfer the user in another table I need read his original primary key..

Comment: I agree the answer is work for the second part. See your question. The other thing I can't understand why are you using `foreach` and `for` loop as per your question your primary value is in `listamicizie1.ValueMember = "IdUtente";` then you can just use `value = listamicizie1.SelectedValue` then `insert` the `value` in to the database.

Comment: I use for because if in the listbox are presents two users for insert the values of idutente for all the users are presents in listbox

Comment: you mean you want to insert all users presented in the list box? right?

Comment: Yes :). sorry for my english  :)

Comment: ok then you have change the code, i will be back in about 30 min, then give you the code.